# How to avoid init session on every prediction when use tf-hub model

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

I followed the way in this post (https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Odry08Jm0f_YALhAt4vp9qa5w8prUzDY#scrollTo=_stfC_7VFhS8) to build a model use universal sentence encoder. Basically the training process is

```
module_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/3" 
embed = hub.Module(module_url)
def UniversalEmbedding(x):
    return embed(tf.squeeze(tf.cast(x, tf.string)), signature="default", as_dict=True)["default"]

input_text = layers.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string)
embedding = layers.Lambda(UniversalEmbedding, output_shape=(embed_size,))(input_text)
dense = layers.Dense(256, activation='relu')(embedding)
pred = layers.Dense(category_counts, activation='softmax')(dense)
model = Model(inputs=[input_text], outputs=pred)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
with tf.Session() as session:
   K.set_session(session)
   session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
   session.run(tf.tables_initializer())
   history = model.fit(train_text, 
        train_label,
        validation_data=(test_text, test_label),
        epochs=10,
        batch_size=32)
  model.save_weights('./model.h5')
```

I save a model weights and hope to use it later. I can load the weights to model via
model.load_weights(self.model_weight_file) 
However, everytime when I need to make a prediction I need to create a session as

```
with tf.Session() as session:
    K.set_session(session)
    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    session.run(tf.tables_initializer())
    predicts = self.model.predict(text)
```

The session init takes long time and it gives me a huge overhead if I need to create a session in every prediction. Is there a way to create a session once and persist to reuse it in every prediction?

Comment: What is `K.set_session`? You should not need to re-init the model ever prediction, you should be able to load an initialize the model once and then loop through your text for multiple inferences.